# Android Row Colour

Tags: android, listview, background, row

I have been trying to get my listview to change background colour during oncreate but have had no luck.

To do this I save either 1 or 0 in the database depending on if it was clicked and colour the rows accordingly. However my rows do not change colour during oncreate.

I have supplied my oncreate and arrayadaptor extends.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_list);

        // Read var from Intent
        Intent intent= getIntent();
        final String ListID = intent.getStringExtra("ListID");
        golbalItemID = ListID;

        ivAdd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAdd);
        ivCancel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCancel);
        tvTotItems = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotItems);

        final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MebmerList = myDb.SelectAllItemData(ListID);       

        myData =  myDb.SelectItemData(Integer.parseInt(ListID.toString())); 

        // listView1
        final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
        registerForContextMenu(lisView1);

        MyAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new MyAdapter(ListItems.this, MebmerList, R.layout.activity_column,
                new String[] {"Name", "Price", "Quan"}, new int[] {R.id.ColName, R.id.ColTel, R.id.ColQuan});      
        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap); 


        lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int position, long mylng) {
                  int iChk = 0;
                // Show Data
                String arrData[] = myDb.SelectItemData((MebmerList.get(position).get("ItemID").toString()));
                if(arrData != null)
                {
                    iChk = Integer.parseInt(arrData[4]);    
                }

                if(iChk == 1)
                {
                    ischkCheck(Integer.parseInt(MebmerList.get(position).get("ItemID").toString()), 0);
                    change_color(lisView1, position, 255, 255, 255);

                    System.out.println("POSITION!ichk=1" + myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    setTitle(myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                }

                else if(iChk == 0)
                {
                    ischkCheck(Integer.parseInt(MebmerList.get(position).get("ItemID").toString()), 1);
                    change_color(lisView1, position, 155, 155, 138);

                    System.out.println("POSITION!ichk=0" + myAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                }

              }});

        ivAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(ListItems.this,AddItem.class);
                newActivity.putExtra("ListID", ListID);
                startActivity(newActivity);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ivCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(ListItems.this,MenuScreen.class);
                startActivity(newActivity); 
                finish();
            }
        });

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(ListItems listItems,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mebmerList,int activityColumn, String[] strings, int[] is) {
            super(listItems, activityColumn, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            System.out.println("POSITION!ichk=1" + "FIRST!");
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

              View view = super.getView( position, convertView, parent );
              view.setBackgroundColor( 0xff00ff00 );
              System.out.println("POSITION!ichk=1" + "MYADGETVIEWP");

              return view;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Edit it clearly, then you can get answers from geeks.

Comment: View view = super.getView( position, convertView, parent );
              view.setBackgroundColor( 0xff00ff00 );

Instead of this try the following view

View view = convertView;
              view.setBackgroundColor( 0xff00ff00 );

Comment: Sorry about that 

I'm trying to set the background colour for individual rows in my listview, I retrieve the info for the colour from my database at runtime and i'm having a few issues trying to figure out how to do that.

When I tried to access the listview in the onCreate, so that i could change the colours I kept getting errors.

Comment: Still no luck with your solution. I also figured out that I am not reaching the getView() method and not sure why this is happening.